# Swift function containing parameters not available in Objective-C class

Tags: objective-c, swift

> UPDATE: This question does not duplicate the question mentioned above.
>   It was verified (see comment below) that the method definition IS
>   properly added to the Project-Swift.h file. The question pertains to
>   why the method without parameters is available to Obj-C and with
>   parameters it is not.

I have a swift class that is intended to be referenced by an Objective-C class. The Swift class contains a function that will be used to send a network message and return a dictionary containing search results. I'm experiencing odd behavior in that if my function contains parameters, it is not available in the implementing Objective-C class. However, if I remove all the parameters, then the function becomes available.

In my Swift class if I declare the method as follows, it is not available in the Obj-C class and won't compile:

```
func getSearchResults(searchText:String?, searchType:String?, zoom:Int?) -> NSDictionary
```

However, removing the parameters like this, the function becomes avaiable to Obj-c and everything works:

```
func getSearchResults() -> NSDictionary
```

Why would a function without parameters be available to an Obj-C class while one containing parameters is not? Has anyone seen this kind of behavior? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Try it without the Int? parameter -- maybe it can't translate that.  2. Check your Project-Swift.h file (the generated header -- replace Project with your project's name) -- see if getSearchResults is there and how it is declared -- maybe it's just not something you expected.

Comment: I checked the Project-Swift.h file and the method is properly declared:
- (NSDictionary * _Nonnull)getSearchResults:(id _Nonnull)searchText searchType:(id _Nonnull)searchType zoom:(NSInteger)zoom;

Comment: @Pheepster: I have double-checked it. `- (NSDictionary * _Nonnull)getSearchResults:(NSString * _Nullable)searchText searchType:(NSString * _Nullable)searchType zoom:(NSInteger)zoom;` is declared in Project-Swift.h *only* if you make the last parameter non-optional `zoom: Int` (or if you remove that parameter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bad boy in your parameter list is the `Int?` param. `Int`'s are represented as `NSInteger` in Objective-C. Thus they don't have a pointer and can't have a `null` value. Consider removing the optional qualifier or changing it to `NSNumber?`,
like: `func getSearchResults(searchText: String?, searchType: String?, zoom: Int) -> NSDictionary`

Comment: This does make sense, however, even this won't compile:
func getSearchResults(searchText:NSString) -> NSDictionary

Comment: Seems that having any parameter at all causes it to be unavailable

Answer (score 2):

Lou Franco's explanation is correct. Your function has an `Int?` parameter, and there is no equivalent of that in Objective-C. Therefore the entire function cannot be exposed to Objective-C. Use `Int` or, if it really can be `nil`, use `NSNumber?`.

Comment: And I would advise using `String` or `NSString?` instead of `String?` as well, because Swift 3 is going to be even stricter about this sort of thing.